# how to solve this nonlinear partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this nonlinear partial differential equation?
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x,t) +b \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x,t) \cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} f(x,t) + a = 0,$$
where $a,b$ are constant.

Comment: Can someone experienced in LaTeX edit this to use proper format?

Comment: Does $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^2$ mean the second partial?

Comment: @Theo: If it is inside `$$...$$`, it's already in displaystyle...

Comment: @aniket: I tried to texify your source, I hope I haven't messed it up. @Arturo: my mistake I clicked on submit too early and thanks for the remark about `\displaystyle`. The original source said `(d/dx)^2`.

Comment: @aniket: no problem, but you should learn it yourself as soon as possible. It's not that hard :). More importantly: Could you please give some context? Where does the problem come from and what have you tried to do?

Comment: @aniket: partial sounds bad, nonlinear partial even worse. Are you searching for a solution or all solutions? (all solutions might be hopeless)

Comment: I think we should give this problem a better go, or at least explain a bit more about the difficulty we are really facing with this type of problem instead of breaking it down to something solvable but not really representative of $f_{xx}+bf_{xx}f_{tt}+a=0$.

Answer (score 4):

You might find some solutions by making the ansatz $f(x,t) = g(x) + h(t)$, i.e., that the solution separates. The equation then reads
$$g''(x) + b \, g''(x) h''(t) +a =0,$$
$$g''(x) [1+ b \,h''(t)] = -a.$$
This equation can be solved by setting $g''(x)=c$ and $1+ b \,h''(t) = -a/c$. The solutions read
$$g(x) = \frac{c}{2} x^2 + c_1 x + c_2$$
and
$$h(t) = -\frac{a+c}{2 b c} t^2 +C_1 t + C_2$$
with $c\neq0$, $c_1$, $c_2$, $C_1$, $C_2$ arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1):

Also it is possible to look for traveling waves solutions $f(x,t)=g(x-сt)\,$. It leads to ODE
$$
g''(x)+bc^2(g''(x))^2+a=0
$$
solutions of which can be written down explicitly:
$$
g(x)=C_1+C_2 x+\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4 a b c^2}}{4 b c^2}x^2. 
$$